# Better way to transform an object in a model Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Suppose I have the following object from an HTTP request:

```
{
  id: 'someid',
  name: 'Jonh',
  age: 23
}
```

and the `user.model.ts`

```
export class User {
  id: string,
  name: string,
  age?: number,
}
```

What is the better approach to creating a new `User` from that object? We can use a `constructor` like this:

```
\\user.model.ts
...
constructor(obj: Object) {
  this.id = obj.id;
  this.name = obj.name
  this.age = obj.age
}
```

And call `new User(object)`. Is there another way to instantiate such model in function of the received object without assigning all model properties (`this.prop = obj.prop`) inside the constructor?

Comment: In fact I think you can just parse the received object to your model and return it inside your http request. I think the heroes tour http example does exactly that

Comment: `return this.http.get<User>(this.userUrl)` should already do the instantiate job without any direct cobstructor call

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Benedikt Schmidt. As I comment on RRForUI answer, this way works in part: the model act as an interface, if I only want the interface members, fine. But if the model had a method, it'd not be available to incoming object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RRForUI answer and Benedikt Schmidt comment solve this problem if I want to model act as an interface.

If I want the object to inherit model properties (if it has some), it won't work (at least in my tests). If the model had `isYoung` method i.e.:

```
\\user.model.ts
...
export class User
{
  public id:string;
  public name:string
  public age :number

  public isYoung?() {
    return this.age < 100  ? true : false;
  }
},
```

the method wouldn't avaiable to object. An approach to solve this is using `Object.assign`:

```
user = Object.assign(new User, user),
```

gives to user (the incoming data from serve) the method `ìsYoung`.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to do it as is.

```
\\user.model.ts
...
export class User
{
  public id:string;
  public name:string
  public age :number
}
```

lets say you get it as below from the service

```
let userData={
  id: 'someid',
  name: 'Jonh',
  age: 23
}
```

then

```
let user=new User();
user=userData;
```

should work

Comment: Thank you for your answer, RRForUI. This way works in part: the model act as an interface, if I only want the interface members, fine. But if the model had a method, it'd not be available to incoming object.